# How to find the position of a letter in a list of words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making this code puzzle, where a user will be given a list of 10 words, encrypted by symbols. Each symbol stands for a letter, and the user will attempt to figure out the words by substituting the symbols with letters:

This is the list of words, saved as 'words'

```
#+/084&"      
#3*#%#+  
8%203:  
,1$&  
!-*%  
.#7&33&
#*#71%  
&-&641'2  
#))85
9&330*
```

The actual list of words is :

```
ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM
```

For example, if the user wishes to substitute '#' with 'A', the syntax will be :
    x = raw_input("what symbol would you like to replace?")
    y = raw_input("what symbol would you like to replace it with?")

The user inputs '#' as 'x', and 'A' as 'y'  :

```
words = words.replace(x,y)
print words
```

and so on...

So far so good..

However, I need to make a function which allows the user to delete a pairing to his/her choice. e.g. :

```
a = raw_input("Which letter would you like to delete")
```

The letter which he has entered should be deleted, and the original symbol which was there initially should be inserted back.
For this, I plan to find the positions of all instances where the letter occurs, and replace it with the original symbol in the same positions, by comparing it with the original list of encrypted words ('words').

Could anyone help me on this?
Any other suggestion/method would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply store the (x,y) combination. To change back to the original, just look up the letter to delete, make the change and remove that combination.

For example:

```
changes = {}
# store first change ('#', 'A')
changes[y] = x
# delete the change
original_x = changes.pop(letter_to_delete)
words.replace(letter_to_delete, original_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your words into arrays of characters so you can iterate through the words for the characters you wish to replace.

some example code:

```
string = "Hello"
splitString = list(string)
splitString
['H','e','l','l','o']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend switching data structures. If you have something like a dictionary of lists, you can have the key be the original encrypted, the 0th item be the unencrypted list, and then append their tries.

So for example:

```
{'ACQUIRED': ['#3*#%#+']
'ALMANAC': ['8%203']}
```

Then, they guess that 8 == j:

```
{'ACQUIRED': ['#3*#%#+', '#3*#%#+']
'ALMANAC': ['8%203', 'J%203']}
```

And you return the 1st elements of the lists as what their guess currently is. If they decide to remove the letter last guessed, you can just pop off the end of the lists.

And then you can just end the program when all of the key, value pairs include a value that is equal to the key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a  dictionary to store each replacement they set or choose to remove.

```
protected void AddKeyButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var encryptedCharacter = txtKeyToAdd.Text;
   var characterToReplace = txtCharToReplace.Text;

   var keys = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   keys.Add(encryptedCharacter, characterToReplace);

   //Add some function to iterate through and replace the characters in
   //your "words" with these values.
}
```

And one to remove...

```
protected void RemoveKeyButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var encryptedCharacter = txtKeyToAdd.Text;

   masterKeys.Remove(encryptedCharacter);

   //Add some function to iterate through and replace the characters in
   //your "words" back to the original values.
}
```

Not sure what language you are using, but this is an example in C#. Look up dictionaries in whatever language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary just pay attention to the fact that python string are immutable so doing just `replace` won't work. 
E.g:

```
>>> s.replace("A","2")
'2CQUIRED'
>>> s
'ACQUIRED'
>>> `
```

So to sum it up you could use something like this example (on [ideone](http://ideone.com/w3D0Ov))

```
s = "AAACQUIRED"
d = {}
for i in xrange(2):
    x = raw_input("what symbol would you like to replace?\n")
    y = raw_input("what symbol would you like to replace it with?\n")
    d[y]=x
    s = s.replace(x,y)
    print s

a = raw_input("Which letter would you like to delete\n")
old = d.pop(a)
s = s.replace(a,old)
print s
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not making it easy?

```
random = ["#+/084&'", "#3*#%#+","8%203:",",1$&","!-*%",".#7&33&","#*#71%","&-&641^2","#))85","9&330*"]
```